# CheckBoxListFor com erro

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, razor

> Descrição: Erro ao compilar um recurso necessário para atender esta solicitação. Examine os detalhes específicos do erro e modifique o código fonte apropriadamente.
>
> Mensagem de Erro do Compilador: CS1061: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' não contém uma definição para 'CheckBoxListFor' e nenhum método de extensão 'CheckBoxListFor' aceita que um primeiro argumento de tipo 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' seja encontrado (você não está usando uma diretriz ou referência de assembly?)

Já baixei a assembly dele, inclusive já até tenho nas referências, mas ele dá esse erro.

E teria como colocar junto com esse checkboxlist, radio buttons e inputs de texto ?

Aqui o código da view:

```
@using MvcCheckBoxList.Model
@model MvcCheckBoxListForApp.Models.FruitViewModel

@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<section class="checkBoxListFor">
  <p>
     <label>Please Select Fruits:</label>
     @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
     {
         @Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.PostedFruits.FruitIds,
                               model => model.AvailableFruits,
                               fruit => fruit.Id,
                               fruit => fruit.Name,
                               model => model.SelectedFruits,
                               Position.Horizontal)
         <input class="green" type="submit"
                value="POST to Controller" />
    }
    </p>
</section>
```

Comment: Baixou como? Instalou o `package` via NuGet?

Comment: Exato, tentei dos dois jeitos, tanto pelo console, tanto pelo NuGet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Exemplo:

1 - ***View***

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.BaseModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Listas";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Listas</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.CheckBoxListFor(
        p => p.BaseSend.Send,
        p => p.BaseAll,
        p => p.Id,
        p => p.Name,
        b => b.BaseSelected            
    )
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
}
```

---

2 - ***Classes***

```
public class Base
{       
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public object Tags { get; set; }
    
}

public class BaseModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Base> BaseAll { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Base> BaseSelected { get; set; }
    public BaseSend BaseSend { get; set; }
}

public class BaseSend
{
    public string[] Send { get; set; }
}
```

---

3 - ***Controller*** (*Método: Listas (GET e POST)*)

```
public ActionResult Listas()
{
    BaseModel baseModel = new BaseModel();

    baseModel.BaseAll = new List<Base>(){
        new Base() { Id = 1, Name="Produto 1", IsSelected = true, Tags="Produtos"},
        new Base()  {Id = 2, Name="Produto 2", IsSelected = false, Tags="Produtos"}
    };

    baseModel.BaseSelected = new List<Base>(){
         new Base() { Id = 1, Name="Produto 1", IsSelected = true, Tags="Produtos"},
    };

    return View(baseModel);
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Listas(BaseSend BaseSend)
{    
    return RedirectToAction("Listas");
}
```

---

4 - **Html Gerado**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

5 - **Recuperando Valores**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

***Todos direitos autorais ao site*** [How to Use CheckBoxListFor With ASP.NET MVC 4?](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/613785/How-to-Use-CheckBoxListFor-With-ASP-NET-MVC)

Comment: Eu fiz o meu inclusive com base nesse link que você mencionou ! Mas o jeito que você fez ficou muito mais claro pra mim ! Mas por exemplo, eu poderia colocar junto com esses check boxes, alguns radio buttons e atrelar aos check boxes um input de texto também ? Tudo num mesmo form, e salvar no banco de dados pra que eu possa depois listar, editar, adicionar e remover ? @FCCDias será que tem como você colocar o código razor também pra gerar esse HTML ?

Comment: Se pode colocar mais `input` de todos os tipos, com model ou simples mais acredito melhor você abrir uma nova pergunta se não disfoca dessa!!!

Comment: Entendi, vou fazer  outra pergunta relacionada a isso também !

Answer (score 1):

Segundo a [documentação](http://mvccbl.com/Documentation):

> Você precisa adicionar a seguinte referência na sua *view* primeiro:

```
@using MvcCheckBoxList.Model
```

Comment: Fiz a alterção e continua dando erro.... Que estrnha porque ta igual ao está aqui http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/613785/How-to-Use-CheckBoxListFor-With-ASP-NET-MVC

Comment: O projeto não está encontrando a `Extension`. Posicionando o curso em cima de `@Html.CheckBoxListFor` e pressionando F12 bem em cima da palavra `CheckBoxListFor`, o que acontece?

Comment: "Cannot navigate to 'CheckBoxListFor'". Muito estranho, porque a referece dele está aqui no projeto.

Comment: O Visual Studio está se perdendo na referência. Feche o Visual Studio e abra-o novamente.

Comment: Pois é, agora funcionou, mas estou tendo outro erro: Detalhes da Exceção: System.EntryPointNotFoundException: O ponto de entrada não foi encontrado.. Estranho, o que pode ser ?

Comment: Isso é quando a DLL usada tem duas versões diferentes, e o VS está se perdendo em qual deve usar.

Comment: Estranho, porque só tenho uma dll instalada. O que devo fazer ? Deletar o projeto e criar de novo ?

Comment: É uma ideia. Eu simplesmente começaria um projeto novo.

Comment: Agora funcionou ! Eu descobri o que era. Quando instala ele da conflito de versões, mas é só ir na barra de navegação lá em cima, abrir a prospectve Error List e clicar em cima do warning que dá, o VS configura tudo certo !